# Finding the shortest path through list of values

Tags: c#

I have been given a list of stations that I need to travel between. The data looks like this:

```
StationName  X   Y

po            1   1
wsx         200 200
edc         300 300
rfv         300 100
tgb         200   0
yhn         100  50
```

I need help with a simple algorithm to find the shortest distance to travel between all stations. I have completed a majority of my code such as finding the euclidean distance but I am stuck on how to compare the list items.

I need a solution that just checks the distance from station A to each other stations and then selects the one with the shortest distance until all have been checked and added.

I have created a Station class and a method for the values I need but I am finding it hard to compare the values that are contained within the list.

Would it be advisable to use a list for each value type e.g.

```
(StationName, X, Y)
```

or create it using a station method? e.g.

```
public Station(string name, double X, double Y)
```

I have a method for calculating my distance between coordinates.

```cs
public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.Pow((y2 - y1), 2) 
                                              * 100000.0 / 100000.0) * 1);
}
```

I am not sure if this enough information to go off. Just let me know and I will provide more.

Comment: I am afraid there is no _simple_ (fast) algo. See Travelling salesman problem, its NP complete.

Comment: NP-hard, no, @MartinMilichovsky?

Comment: @spender you are right, and so am I (its both NP-hard and NP-C). Steve, your described solution is _greedy_ and would not return optimal (shortest) path.